# C# how to have a message form that sits on top of other forms?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a windows application written in C#.  It has a few areas where the main thread does some processing and database access - this basically locks the GUI.  As this is legacy code - I do not want to touch this at this point.

What I would like to do is to be able to have a message 'form' that I can display over the main form - let the main form do its job - and then close the secondary form after the main form has completed it task.  As this has to work in a few different forms in the application - I am looking to create a somewhat generic method that I can use and reuse through out the application.

I have something implemented by using a secondary thread to create the message form - but it has one draw back at this point - the user can still click on the main form and do things...  The Message form goes behind the main form when the user clicks on the main form.

Here is what I am hoping to do...

Main Form

```
Create and display Message Form
-----
Longish running task starts  
   Send update messages to the Message Form - to update the user
Longish running task ends
----- 
Close and Destroy Message Form
```

While the main form longish running task is going - I would like to prevent the user from interacting with the main form...   What I have sort of works - but I am looking for the best or proper way of doing this sort of thing.

Does anyone have any links to how best to do this message form sort of thing?

Bradley

Comment: Since long running operation executed on main (UI) thread, main form will be already not available for interactions.

Comment: Fabio - normally you would be correct - but this is a series of operations - and it is possible for the user to interact with the main form... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        //Before your processing is started
        this.Enabled = false;
        Form form = new YourForm();
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.Focus();
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => form.ShowDialog());
        thread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest; //<- just an example, set it according to your need
        thread.Start();

        //Enter your processing code here

        //After your processing is completed
        form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            form.Close();
        });
        thread.Abort();
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Enabled = true;
        this.Focus();
        this.TopMost = false;
```

Comment: Hello Afnan - a good solution - with one issue.  It appears that when I run the last line "this.TopMost = false" - it makes my main form go in behind all the other forms in Windows.   So - even if I have just Explorer open - after this line of code is run - my application's main form ends up in behind it..    However, then I get rid of the TopMost true/false setting - it works pretty much as I had hoped!!      Thank you very much for your response!!

Comment: You're welcome, you can mark this as the answer then